mpm_prefork:error AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting, and server down
I ran into a problem: my web server crashes about once every 1-2 days. I looked at the logs and realized that during a crash in Apache the following error occurs:
first error:
[Wed May 01 17:11:28.778759 2024] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 1430980] AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting

then there are a lot of warnings and after that the server stops working
[Wed May 01 17:11:28.778759 2024] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 1430980] AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting
[Wed May 01 17:12:25.663388 2024] [fcgid:warn] [pid 1843930] mod_fcgid: process 2119707 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Wed May 01 17:12:25.663432 2024] [fcgid:warn] [pid 1843930] mod_fcgid: process 2119872 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Wed May 01 17:12:29.069787 2024] [fcgid:warn] [pid 1843930] mod_fcgid: process 2121664 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Wed May 01 17:12:29.069831 2024] [fcgid:warn] [pid 1843930] mod_fcgid: process 2121668 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Wed May 01 17:12:29.069841 2024] [fcgid:warn] [pid 1843930] mod_fcgid: process 2121670 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Wed May 01 17:12:29.069849 2024] [fcgid:warn] [pid 1843930] mod_fcgid: process 2121666 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Wed May 01 17:12:29.069856 2024] [fcgid:warn] [pid 1843930] mod_fcgid: process 2121665 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Wed May 01 17:12:29.069863 2024] [fcgid:warn] [pid 1843930] mod_fcgid: process 2121663 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL

I started digging into the mpm_prefork.conf config, here is my configuration:
StartServers            5
MinSpareServers         5
MaxSpareServers         10
MaxRequestWorkers       150
MaxConnectionsPerChild  0

maybe try increasing MaxRequestWorkers? But to what extent I don’t know, and perhaps if this is increased, other parameters need to be changed
